# Inheriting from JavaScript function in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I have a following JavaScript base function:

```
function Animal { }  

Animal.prototype.move = function () { 
  //... 
}
```

I have also a derived JavaScript function like this:

```
function Dog {
  Dog.super_.call(this);
}

util.inherits(Dog, Animal);

Dog.prototype.bark = function () {
  // ...
}
```

Now I would like to create a C++ addon which is exactly the same as the derived
`Dog` JavaScript function:

```
void Dog::Init(Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module) {
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();

  Local<Function> require = Local<Function>::Cast(module->Get(
    String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "require")));

  Local<Value> args[] = {
    String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "./animal")
  };  

  Local<Value> animalModule = require->Call(module, 1, args);

  Local<Function> animalFunc = Local<Function>::Cast(animalModule);   

  Local<FunctionTemplate> tpl = FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, New);
  // tpl->Inherit(animalFunc); // <-- HERE
  tpl->SetClassName(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Dog"));
  tpl->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);  

  NODE_SET_PROTOTYPE_METHOD(tpl, "bark", Bark);

  constructor.Reset(isolate, tpl->GetFunction());
  exports->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Dog"),
    tpl->GetFunction());    
}
```

How can I get a `FunctionTemplate` from `animalFunc` / `animalModule` to be able to inherit from it in `tpl` function template? Or maybe I should somehow assign *animalFunc.prototype* to *tpl.prototype*?

Answer (score 0):

Alas, you can't.

Check this discussion: https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/issues/229

It is the main reason why there is no standard way of inheriting JS classes in C++.